# How do I generate fruit with the Fruitful Staff?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I've purchased the Fruitful Staff for a small fortune, hoping for an endless supply of fruit, but I can't figure out how to create fruit with it. Do I have to physically attack something with it? And if I do, is fruit generation guaranteed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you must [beat your enemies senseless with it](http://www.quartertothree.com/game-talk/showpost.php?s=3703ee1607743268e478e52d4f179455&p=2822592&postcount=1636).  Every killing blow with the staff causes fruit to drop.

Go forth and [fructify](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fructify)!